# Turtlesim: Stop after one turn. Subscriber way faster than the Publisher

Tags: publisher, turtlesim, subscribers

I am interested in drawing one circle with the *turtlesim*. However the subscriber is retrieving the pose way faster than the publishers moves the turtle. This is the code that I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist 
from turtlesim.msg import Pose

locations = []

def pose_callback(pose:Pose):
    global locations

    msg = Twist()
    msg.linear.x = 2.0 
    msg.angular.z = 1.0

    pub.publish(msg)
    
    rospy.sleep(0.5) # delay on subscribing 
    locations.append((pose.x,pose.y))
    rospy.loginfo(locations)
    if (pose.x, pose.y) in locations:
        rospy.loginfo(f'Circle completed!')
        rospy.signal_shutdown('Completed circle')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('draw_one_circle', disable_signals=True) 
    pub = rospy.Publisher("/turtle1/cmd_vel", Twist, queue_size=10)
    sub = rospy.Subscriber("/turtle1/pose", Pose, callback=pose_callback)
    
    rospy.loginfo("Node has been started.")

    rospy.spin()
```

Any tip on what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're giving open loop commands but expecting precise positioning in your stop condition. This may succeed in the simplest of simulators, but it's a recipe for disaster with any real system or realistic simulation.

You need to introduce some amount of feedback, and adjust your commanded velocity twist amount to be dependent on how far along your desired path your robot is. It's a very large change to your algorithm, but it will allow you to drive circles (or any path) while dealing with real world disturbances like different floor types, carpets, and humans.

If you're really trying to hack together a simple circle, you'll want to change your twist values (`msg.linear` and `msg.angular`) so the robot completes 1 circle with an integer number of messages and then just send that number of messages. This code will be useless outside of this particular setup though.

Comment: Thank you so much :)